# Bad Mail format in Outlook but fine in Gmail

Tags: c#, email

i have created a function which send an email having large HTML data containing many in-line styling and images.

HTML body is set to true.

The Email appears fine in GMAIL with all styling and images but in Outlook the format got distracted.

Do outlook requires something more to make email exactly like in Gmail?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yep, outlook uses its own html, which isn't quite the same as the default markup. Been bitten by that one before too. For example floats are not supported with normal markup, but need special mso tags. One place to look with several tips: http://robcubbon.com/create-html-email-newsletters-outlook/

Comment: thanks for precious suggestion, i will refine my HTMl

Comment: P.S. I've got some code lying around that sets the html of a mailitem based on the input of a webbrowser control, but it's only useful when setting an Outlook interop mailitem directly from a winforms webbrowser control. It resolves pagewidth, absolute positions and embedded images. (It was made for a very specific goal back then, hence the need for the control). It probably is of no use in this scenario, but in the off chance that it is, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Me.Name

your link help me to solve the issue, steps mentioned in below link help in creating HTML for outlook view

http://robcubbon.com/create-html-email-newsletters-outlook/